# What's the advantage of a pre-built stove/fire/barrel?

Tags: the-long-dark

When playing the long dark, I can easily make a fire outdoors. I even get the stones for free, all I need is matches, tinder, fuel (and accelerant is optional).

Now sometimes I discover locations with a pre-built fire opportunity: a barrel, a stove, a belly pot fire...

However, I still need the same 3 ingredients, and the chance to start the fire seems the same to.

So are there any advantages to using a pre-built fire (say, a barrel in a train wreck) as opposed to just making your own fire?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A benefit of stoves is that they have [six cooking slots](https://thelongdark.fandom.com/wiki/Stove) compared to the camprfire's two cooking slots, allowing you to prepare more food quickly.

Likewise, stoves and other contained fires are found indoors or covered areas where you're sheltered from the elements and can search for supplies while your food cooks.

The third benefit of permanent cooking fixtures is that fires created in these [can not be blown out](https://thelongdark.fandom.com/wiki/Fire), unlike a crafted campfire which is vulnerable to the wind and weather.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that "contained fires, such as stoves in ruined houses, will not frighten approaching predators" per the wiki.